# How can this spinner item be null?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, null-pointer

I have a spinner that gets its data from an ArrayAdapter. The array object has a toString() method and this is used by the spinner.

In this case I am setting the adapter when there is just one item in the array. The object in the array returns a not null String, but although the spinner has one item in it, it is null. Why is there not a valid TextView as an item in the spinner. Here is the program breakpointed just after the adapter has been set:

[image: Breakpoint]

Here is the problem:

[image: Expressions]

Here is the MolData class

```
final class MolData
{
    private String name;
    private String value;
    final static Pattern endsDot = Pattern.compile("[.]$");

    MolData(String name, String value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    MolData(String fileLine)
    {
        int dividerPos = fileLine.indexOf(':');
        value = fileLine.substring(0, dividerPos);
        name = fileLine.substring(dividerPos + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    boolean hasName(String name)
    {
        return name.equals(this.name);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    boolean isAfterName(String name)
    {
        if (this.value.equals(""))
        {
            return true;
        }
        int cmp = name.toLowerCase().compareTo(this.name.toLowerCase());
        if (cmp == 0)
        {
            cmp = name.compareTo(this.name);
        }
        return cmp > 0;
    }

    boolean hasValue(String value)
    {
        return this.value.equals(endsDot.matcher(value).replaceFirst(""));
    }
}
```

Abd here is the code with the problem:

```
void finaliseSpinner(Spinner memSpinner, View molValue)
{
    this.memSpinner = memSpinner;
    this.molValue = (TextView) molValue;
    if (! restart)
    {
        memSpinner.setVisibility((molData.isEmpty() || (molData.size() == 1 && molData.get(0).hasValue(""))) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        spinerColour1st = true;
    }
    memSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<MolData>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, molData));
    ignoreItemSelected = true;
    memSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinListener());
}
```

Further clarification: The problem I hit was that getChildAt(0) returned null in the OnItemSelected listener. However when this code is invoked in a normal start-up, though getChildCount shows zero after the adapter is set, when the listener is set immediately afterwards, the invocation of the listener caused by its addition has a valid getChildAt(0) ! But when this code is invoked because the screen has been rotated, getChildAt(0) is null when the listener fires because it has been added. On a normal start-up this code is invoked from user interaction with the UI, but after the screen is restarted this code (in a fragment) is invoked from onResume(). [ It was invoked from onCreate but I moved it later in the life cycle to see if it helped, without success. ]

Comment: check getChildCount()

Comment: getChildCount() is 0. But how can this be when I have just set an array adapter that has one element?

Comment: I've added some more detail about when the problem occurs.

Comment: Creation of views using `ListView` is asynchronous, so you might have an object in your adapter, without its corresponding view having been created

Comment: So if I"m understanding you correctly, this works fine until a screen rotation? If so, can you show the code on how you load the fragment and how these methods are called? As the current code you posted seems fine.

Comment: The fragment is inflated automatically when the activity inflates its layout from XML as both orientations contain a <fragment> tag. It does not matter which way the orientation change goes, the problem exists. The method shown above is triggered from the activity in response to the user interacting with the UI normally, but from onResume after a rotation. I am sure the problem lies with the fact that, as pointed out by Antoine above) that ListView is asynchronous. I'm still not 100% sure about this, as I had a breakpoint waiting after setting the adapter and before setting the listener.

Comment: I will endevour to redesign so as not to access the first child view within the listener. However this has given me another worry which I will post as another question if I can't find the answer. The fragment might add and/or remove items from the list, and change the selected item possition when it has notified the adapter of the data change. What happens if it adds an item to the end of the list and then sets the position to that last entry before the spinner has refreshed its views?